# Функция должна найти набор подстрок "s", которые удовлетворяют условиям

Tags: java

Например, дана строка:

> s = 's02'

Набор подстрок s будет:

> {"0", "02", "2", "s", "s0", "s02"}

Если уменьшить только до тех подстрок, которые начинаются с буквы и заканчиваются цифрой, останутся

> {"s0", "s02"}

Первый буквенно-цифровой элемент в этом сокращенном списке - «s0», а последний буквенно-цифровой элемент - «s02».

Нужно завершить функцию `findSubstrings`. У нее 1 параметр: строку inputString, состоящую из строчных букв английского алфавита [a - f] и цифр [0 - 9]

Функция должна найти набор подстрок s:

- Последний символ подстроки должен быть числом
- Первый символ подстроки должен быть буквой

  ```
  public class Solution {
     public String findSubstrings(String inputString){
     return "";
  }

      @Test
      public void testFindSubstring1() {
         Assert.assertTrue(findSubstrings("a01").equals("a0 a01"));
      }

      @Test
      public void testFindSubstring2() {
         Assert.assertTrue(findSubstrings("7961686f6f").equals("f6 f6"));
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        JUnitCore.main("Solution");
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данный вопрос я решил с помощью двух `for-loop`.

Идея проста:
Есть два индекса: `i` и `j`. for-loop с `i` проходится с первого символа и проверяет, что нынешний символ (`...charAt(i)`) является буквой (`Charecter.isLetter...`). В случае если символ является буквой, запускается for-loop с `j`, который ищет цифры, которые идет **после** буквы на позиции `i` (отсюда `j = i + 1`). В случае, если символ по индексу `j` является цифрой, то запускаем "обрезатель строки" (`.substring(int begin, int finish)`). Стоит отметить, что нам надо будет в нем прибавить к концу обрезания +1, потому что данный метод обрезает до указанного индекса, исключая финальную часть -> `inputString.substring(i, j+1)`.

Ниже приведен обобщенный вид алгоритма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SO so = new SO();

        System.out.println(so.findSubstrings("S74ck0verf10w").toString());
    }

    public List<String> findSubstrings (String inputString){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length() - 1; i++) {

            // check if char is letter
            if(Character.isLetter(inputString.charAt(i))) {

                for (int j = i + 1; j < inputString.length(); j++) {
                    if(Character.isDigit(inputString.charAt(j))){
                        list.add(inputString.substring(i, j+1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. что если мне нужно чтобы этот код прошел через тесты в том же классе что и сама функция проверки? посмотрите пожалуйста на обновленный код выше.

Comment: @Lev Это уже гуглить надо Вам. Рассмотри создание отдельного класса JUnit 5 теста и [рассмотри вот эту ссылку про тест листов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495420/how-to-junit-test-that-two-liste-contain-the-same-elements-in-the-same-order)

Comment: @Lev можете отметить, пожалуйста, ответ галкой, если я ответил на ваш изначальный вопрос